# Is it possible to run a helm or other completion command for hydra window?

Tags: hydra

Spacemacs offers many hydra window to show various keys.
(And my question is not specific to spacemacs, just hydra in general)
Sometimes there are many commands so it's hard to find what's there.

Is it possible to grep on those key descriptions in hydra window?

I use `describe-keymap` or `describe-bindings` but I think being able to explore the hydra window might be helpful

[image]

The hydra window (bottom section) shows many commands, is it possible to search (like isearch or similar) those commands rather than trying to find them by eyes?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Try asking how to do some specific thing, rather than a vague "is it possible..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example image shows a 'which-key' buffer, not a 'hydra'. You can try pressing `SPC w .` to see an example of a hydra.

I don't know of an easy way to search the which-key buffer, but you can do
`M-: (setq which-key-persistent-popup t)`, then navigate to the which key menu you'd like to search and get out by pressing `C-g`. Now you can select it e.g. by pressing `SPC w w`. Finally, you can search the buffer like any normal buffer (e.g. using `/` or `SPC s s`). You can also close the buffer like any normal buffer (e.g. `SPC b d`).

Of course to make this easier, you could make a command to toggle the value of
`which-key-persistent-popup` (and optionally bind it to some convenient key sequence).

```lisp
(defun my-toggle-which-key-persistent ()
  (interactive)
  (setq which-key-persistent-popup (not which-key-persistent-popup)))
```

An alternative solution, which more or less does exactly what you are asking for, can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/otjn19/comment/h6vyx9q/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (I found it only after writing this answer).

Comment: oh the embark thing seems to do exactly what I wanted. gonna try soon. thank you